# Fail to access https website config by mod_ssl on CentOS

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, tcp, centos

I installed and config mod_ssl in httpd service on CentOS like this link: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-6

And this is my config in httpd.conf:

```html
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
<Directory /var/www/html/source>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/source
ServerName sub.domain.com.vn
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/source
ServerName sub.domain.com.vn
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

x.x.x.x is my server IP
And the problem is I can access http:// sub.domain.com.vn but can not access to https:// sub.domain.com.vn. I can telnet to port 443 normally. Port 443 and HTTPS protocol is ready.

## netstat -tap | grep https

tcp 0 0 *:https *:* LISTEN 1

## netstat -tlnp | grep 443

tcp 0 0 :::443 :::* LISTEN 1

But when I access to https:// sub.domain.com.vn it print out a error "This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED". Can anybody give me a help please ? Forgive me if my english not good enough. Port 443 on my server is opened, I checked.

Comment: Could be many reasons, did you restart apache after finishing changes? Do you have proper keys and permissions set? What do logs say?

Comment: I sure with you that i restart httpd after finishing changes, logs say
"[warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) 'xxxxxxx' does NOT match server name!?"

Comment: Did u buy sertificate for subdomain, or for www.yourdomain?